# Get the object position by using bwconncomp in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

For segmentation, there is a function in matlab `bwconncomp`. It can calculate the number of detected objects.

```
  Im=imread('Mountain.ppm');
  [Seg_Im] = normalize_segmentation(Im);
  Im_filt=medfilt2(Seg_Im,[3 3]);

  se=strel('disk',2);
  Seg_Im = imclose(Im_filt,se);
  Obj_Im= bwconncomp(Seg_Im,6)

  Obj_Im = 

Connectivity: 6
   ImageSize: [30 32]
  NumObjects: 1
PixelIdxList: {[129x1 double]}
```

And when I acces the `PixelIdxList`, the maximum value is 834.

What is that 834? Because the image size is only 30x32.

And how we can get the positon of the object by using the `PixelIdxList`/`bwconncomp` information?

Answer (score 1):

A look at the manual will tell you that it is a linear index:

```
 PixelIdxList:   1-by-NumObjects cell array where the kth element
                 in the cell array is a vector containing the linear
                 indices of the pixels in the kth object.
```

If you want them in an `x` and `y` format, use the `ind2sub` function:

```
[x,y]=ind2sub(size(Im), Obj_Im.PixelIdxList)
```

One example:

```
[x,y]=ind2sub(size(Im), 834)

x =

    24

y =

    28
```

Comment: I get an error for the same." Undefined function 'minus' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Error in ind2sub (line 35)
    vi = rem(ndx-1, siz(1)) + 1;"

Comment: @MojoJojo I'm guessing ndx is PixelIdxList from my answer? Then it's a cell array and you cannot subtract 1 from a cell array. Also, what does "siz()" do?